# Why are on-wake sound issues solved by opening System Settings?

Tags: release-loki, settings, sound, hdmi

I am trying to find a workaround for the following problem.

I use a Radeon HD 6000 series pci express graphics card with a HDMI output to a tv.

After waking from suspend, no sound.

Opening Pavucontrol tells me the HDMI port is unplugged.

If I have left the sound pane of System Settings open, I can see the HDMI port under 'Play sound through' has disappeared.

Restarting the system or or re-launching System Settings solves the issue.

So: what is the sequence of events when System Settings opens, and can I automate this on-wake to restore HDMI sound automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a problem introduced by Pulseaudio 8.

Pulseaudio 9 claims to fix the problem (See "Automatic routing improvements", [Pulseaudio 9 Release notes](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Notes/9.0/)).

Upgrading to Pulseaudio 9 doesn't seem possible in Loki or is beyond my techincal level. (EDIT: [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/872267) is someone trying it in Ubuntu 16.04 and running into unmet dependencies, as I did...).

I even tried [removing Pulseaudio entirely and falling back on Gnome-Alsa-Mixer](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-pulseaudio-use-alsa-ubuntu-linux/) or QASmixer. Neither recognised my HDMI output.

**An answer**

While it doesn't directly answer my question, [this suggestion on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/840679) provided me with a quick'n'dirty solution to the problem.

It might only have been a minor annoyance, but now I can switch my TV between games console and HTPC without having to jigger with the HTPC sound settings every time.

I look forward to Juno on the assumption it will use a more recent version of Pulseaudio.